# SOQL Query refactoring

Tags: apex, soql

I have a `Parent_Object__c` with two string fields `Number1__c` and `Number2__c`. The `Number2__c` value for one record might be the same as `Number1__c` value for another record. My end goal is to populate two look-ups of `Parent_Object__c` on a `Child_Object__c`. The records of `Child_Object__c`is being created from external integration with `Parent_Number1__c` field.

Conditions to populate to those two look-ups are:

1. `Parent_Number1__c` = `Number1__c` field of Parent_Object__c
2. Once you get the above lookup, get the `Number2__c` field from that parent record and find another parent record that has the same `Number1__c` value.

On `Child_Object__c` trigger:

```
 set<string> parentNum1Values = new set<string>();
    for(Child_Object__c ch:Trigger.New)
    {
        parentNum1Values.add(ch.Parent_Number1__c);
    }
 set<string> parentNum2Values = new set<string>();

 map<string, string> Num1toNum2Map = new map<string, string>();
 map<string, Id> Num1LookUpMap = new map<string, Id>();
 map<string, Id> Num2LookupMap = new map<string, Id>();
    for(Parent_Object__c po:[select Id, Number1__c, Number2__c from Parent_Object__c 
                             where Number1__c IN :parentNum1Values])
    {
       if(po.Number1__c != po.Number2__c){
            parentNum2Values.add(po.Number2__c);
            Num1toNum2Map.put(po.Number1__c, po.Number2__c); //used when assigning lookups
       }

       Num1LookUpMap.put(po.Number1__c, po.Id);
    }
    for(Parent_Object__c po:[select Id from Parent_Object__c 
                             where Number1__c IN :parentNum2Values])
    {
       Num2LookupMap.put(po.Number1__c, po.Id);
    }
```

Can I refactor those two soql queries into one query?

Comment: No you can't join them into one. Not sure why you are getting down votes but you're not going to be able to simplify here.

Comment: I'd love to have comments on what is wrong with the question before down-voting. It helps me to ask them in the right way.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thank you. I know I voted for the right moderator :)

Comment: Not sure what's with the downvotes, so I've upvoted to offset one of them. Does seem like more people are willing to downvote after someone else already has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're stuck with two queries here. You can't use joins on any field type outside of relationships, and they don't work on hierarchical relationships either (same object as child and parent).